# How do I build a zero-block team on Marvel Contest of the Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

I've read many many posts about zero-block teams, aka block proficiency teams. But I have yet to understand how to build a team like that.

My question is, when I am building a team, how do I figure out that a team will have zero block damage (perfect block)?

Please note that I am not asking for a list of all possible zero-block teams.

Comment: FYI - Since July 2016 those teams are not possible anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Perfect block teams were nerfed in a recent patch. You can no longer create a team that takes 0 damage when blocking in Contest of Champions. The game creators felt it was unfair to players who didn't have the characters required to build those teams.

---

"Perfect block" teams are unfortunately somewhat of a misnomer in Marvel's Contest of Champions, due to the fact that there's a Perfect Block Mastery that has nothing to do with creating a perfect block team. The stat you want to pay attention to is **Block Proficiency**. Specifically, you want to make sure that your team has at least a 43% Block Proficiency in order to take zero damage while blocking.

To do this, you want to do two things:

1. Maximize your Block Proficiency Mastery (under Defense) to 4/4 for an 8% increase.
2. Put together teams that have the Leadership Synergy bonus, which gives an additional boost to Block Proficiency.

For example, when I pair up my 4-star Dr. Strange with 4-star Scarlet Witch, I get a 20% increase to Block Proficiency.

[image: Block Proficiency]

If I also add my 3-star Dr. Strange to this team, I get an additional 15% Block Proficiency, for a total of

20% + 15% + 8% = 43%

I'm already at my goal with only three characters. Since the Synergy Bonus screen tells us that *All Champions* gain the block proficiency, I can add any other two champions I want to round out my team. All of them will have "perfect block."